# Flushing TCP Incoming Stream?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I am building a iPad app (Object C) and its pure purpose is to receive information from a wireless device. I can connect fine and receive information but sometimes the incoming stream has information I don't want. Is there a way to flush the incoming stream to clear all incoming bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Just skip it.